# What's the use of the [python-chess] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Is there anything that the rarely-used (only about 20 questions) [python-chess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-chess) tag achieves that [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [chess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chess) can't?

If not, should it be burninated?

Comment: And on top of that, 10% of the questions using it are your own questions ;)

Comment: As per [The burnination guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/363946), the [tag:python-chess] tag doesn't meet the 1st, 2nd, or 4th criteria for burnination. It's unambiguous, on topic, and you don't give any indication of it meaning anything else in common contexts. Your argument about [tag:python] + [tag:chess] only addresses the 3rd point of burnination; that it's not adding anything useful to the post.

Answer (score 16):

https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess

> python-chess is a pure Python chess library with move generation, move validation and support for common formats.

The tag should not be burninated, instead it should be given a proper excerpt and wiki.

Comment: I didn't understand what the tag was (that it's referencing a library).

Comment: @Alec_a That's why it should be given a proper except and wiki, so that you and everyone else can know what it's referencing.

Comment: A quick look through the questions with that tag (other than your own) should have suggested the presence of such a library, @alec_a.